# Internet Explorer specific html unordered list error

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, mozilla

I want to remove the bullet icon provided by the `<ul></ul>` HTML tag and in place I need a dash sign as the bullet. I've written the following code. It works perfectly fine with mozilla firefox, however IE 2013 shows both the circular bullet icon as well. It seems to be the browser specific problem. How do I fix this error? Regards!

```
@foreach (var CareerList in Model)
{
    <ul type="none">
        @foreach (var item in CareerList.skills)
        {
            <li>- @item.ToString()</li>                                          
        }
        <br />
    </ul>   
}
```

IE shows like following:

> - Skills Required:
>
>   - Knowledge of .NET framework, C#, ASP.NET MVC, .EXT, HTML& Javascript.
>   - Minimum working experience of 1 year.

Comment: wtf is `@foreach...`?

Comment: Why don't you use CSS for this?

Comment: @MightyPork `@foreach` is from a C# Razor view

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

This way, you can remove the circle bullet (default list-style icon in browsers) and the dash will be previewed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style

Answer (score 0):

You could change the `list-style`. [Documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-type.asp).

```
<ul type="none">
```

To

```
<ul style="list-style:none;">
```

---

However I would recommend you don't use inline CSS, see below.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="myList">
```

**CSS**

```
.myList {
    list-style:none;
}
```